# Convert milliseconds to Time without losing precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`Time.current` gives me precision beyond seconds:

```
> Time.current
Fri, 11 Feb 2022 23:00:18.253185000 UTC +00:00
> Time.current.to_f
1644620430.942064
```

But `Time.at` loses the precision :(

```
> Time.at(1644620430.942064).utc
2022-02-11 23:00:30 UTC
```

The whole `.942064` got truncated. This is messing with some tests that compare dates, because timestamps seem to save with the milliseconds, but I don't know how to create a Time that includes milliseconds

How can I cast a variable of milliseconds into a Time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you need nanoseconds precision

[`Time::at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-c-at) has such form

```
time = Time.current
# => Fri, 11 Feb 2022 23:36:25.983398537 UTC +00:00

float_time = time.to_f
# => 1644622585.9833987

secs = float_time.floor
# => 1644622585

nsecs = time.nsec
# => 983398537

Time.at(secs, nsecs, :nsec).utc
# => 2022-02-11 23:36:25.983398537 UTC
```

You can choose precision using one of these keys:

- `:msec` is the number of milliseconds (`Integer`, `Float`, or `Rational`) in the range `0..1000`
- `:usec` is the number of microseconds (`Integer`, `Float`, or `Rational`) in the range `0..1000000`
- `:nsec` key is the number of nanoseconds (`Integer`, `Float`, or `Rational`) in the range `0..1000000000`

You can also just call [`utc`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-utc) on `Time.current`

```
time = Time.current
# => Fri, 11 Feb 2022 23:36:25.983398537 UTC +00:00

time.utc
# => 2022-02-11 23:36:25.983398537 UTC
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just seeing a formatting problem. Consider:

```
Time.at(1644620430.942064).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N')
# 2022-02-11T15:00:30.942064046
```

However, if you call [`to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-to_s):

```
Time.at(1644620430.942064).to_s
# "2022-02-11 15:00:30 -0800" 
Time.at(1644620430.942064).utc.to_s
# "2022-02-11 23:00:30 UTC"
```

you only get results with one second resolution.

The full precision time is there but you need to be careful to ask for it when you format your time.

Comment: The round trip to float adds a small precision loss, though. (not necessarily in time resolution, but the typical float issues apply)